# modal, button on modal executing many time

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I am trying to send data on button on modal using jQuery, first time it is working well but when I click second time it execute twice and for third time it execute 3 times, I want to execute that button only once, what is wrong exactly?
my modal

```
`<div id="Modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content modal-sm">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">product</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
       <label>Quantity</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="qty" value="">
       <label>Note:</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="note" value="">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button id="" type="button" class="btn btn-primary mdismiss" data-dismiss="modal">Add</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>`
```

my jQuery :

`

```
$('#btnbtn').click(function(){
   $('#Modal').modal('show');
    $('#addbutton').click(function(){
    alert();
  });
});`
```

Comment: add `e.stopPorpagation()`

Comment: Please, give me you full js code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding `click` handler multiple time whenever you are clicking on `#btnbtn` button. No need of attaching `click` event handler to `#addbutton` on each click. Change your code like below:

```
    $('#btnbtn').click(function(){
       $('#Modal').modal('show');
    });

   $('#addbutton').click(function(){
        alert();
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using .click() when binding the button you can use [one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/). It will only execute once.

```
$('#btnbtn').click(function(){
   $('#Modal').modal('show');
    $('#addbutton').one('click', function(){
    alert();
  });
});`
```